# Change focus on button click in vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have a button and a textbox in vf page. I want when i click the button the focus should go to textbox. Below is my vf page -

```
<apex:actionregion >
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.RFP__c.Fields.Country__c.Label}" style="width:87%; float:right;height:0px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;color:#2F4F4F;"/>

                        <apex:outputPanel id="countries" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredInput" style="width:82%; float:right;">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="countr" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredBlock"/>
                            <apex:selectList value="{!discountScheduleID}" size="1" styleClass=" chzn-select" >
                                <!--      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}" rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()" />  -->
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!dept}" />
                            </apex:selectList> 
                        </apex:outputPanel>

                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.RFP__c.Fields.Type__c.Label}" style="width:87%; float:right;height:5px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;color:#2F4F4F;"/>

                        <apex:outputPanel id="type" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredInput" style="width:82%; float:right;">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="type1" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredBlock"/>
                            <apex:selectList value="{!TypeID}" size="1" styleClass=" chzn-select" >
                                <!--           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}" rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()" />  -->
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Type}" />
                            </apex:selectList> 
                        </apex:outputPanel>

                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 


                    <div style="width:10%;margin-left:260px;">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Search Regions"  style="width:150%; float:right;height:5px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;color:#2F4F4F;"/>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="type" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredInput" style="width:82%; float:right;">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="type1" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredBlock"/>
                            <apex:inputText id="searchtext" value="{!searchTerm}" />

                        </apex:outputPanel>


                        <apex:commandbutton value="Search" action="{!FindAllName}" rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()" style="width:120px;margin-left:30px;" status="actStatusId" id="cmdbutton" />    
                    </div>

                    <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId">
                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                            <apex:image url="/img/loading32.gif" width="15" height="15"  style="float:left;margin-left: 430px;;margin-top:-16px;"/>              
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>


                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="geo">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.RFP__c.Fields.Geography__c.Label}"  style="width:87%; float:right;height:12px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;color:#2F4F4F;"/>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="geographies" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredInput" style="width:82%; float:right;margin-top:-10px;">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="geos" layout="block"  styleClass="requiredBlock"/>
                            <apex:outputText value="Please Refine Your Search" rendered="{!IF(results >1000,'true','false')}" style="margin-left:-2px;width:100%; margin-top:-10px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;color:red;"/>
                            <apex:outputText value="No Results Found" rendered="{!IF(results ==0,'true','false')}" style="margin-left:-2px;width:100%; margin-top:-10px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;color:black;"/>
                            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedGeographyIds }" multiselect="true" id="selectedGeographies" styleClass="fullWidth chzn-select" >

                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllName}" id="movieTextBox"></apex:selectOptions>

                            </apex:selectList>

                            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="errorMsg" >
                                <apex:outputText value="{!errorMap['selectedGeographies']}" 
                                                 escape="false" rendered="{!errorMap['selectedGeographies'] != ''}" />
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:actionregion>  

Regards
```

Comment: I don't see any input. Do you mean the select box/picklist? And what are you attempting now that isn't working?

Comment: Hi Peter.. I have edited the vf page. Search Regions is the inputtext where i need to put the string which i need to search. On command button click i will render the result in the selectlist region...I want when i click the button the focus should come to outputpanel id="geographies"..

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this piece of code

```
document.getElementById("myText").focus();
```

invoke this or call this from your button click. It will work for you.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lmcculley/rYfvQ/)

Answer (score 0):

You can call a custom javascript function on button click and then set focus on the textbox as mentioned by @tushar

Please check sample code :

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputText id="searchtext">
    <apex:commandButton value="Mark" onClick="setFocus();return false;"/>
</apex:form>
```

and add this in Visualforce page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setFocus()
  {
     document.getElementById("searchtext").focus();
  }
</script>
```